# jQuery - Run a function based on text match

Tags: jquery

I've had a search through the site and can't find an answer, so here goes:

I would like to know how one could run a function based on a text match with jQuery. Let me explain further.

I have 3 groups of numbers, we'll call each group A, B and C respectively.

An example scenario:

A user will enter some text into an Input box, push submit and jQuery will check if the input text matches any text contained within one of the groups and if so, return some data to say 'Input text matches text from group A' and run one of 3 functions based on what's returned.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can try for If condition. So only the exact text will be matched.

Comment: it's kind of lame to ask a question like this, when you could get an answer by googling it, especially with such a simple feature as text matching and if statements. Take a course in computer programming for goodness sake! what you're looking for is an `if { } elseif {}` statement using `somestring.match(regex)` or `somestring.indexOf(string) > 0`

Comment: Thanks Anoop and Illaya. Serakfalcon, grow up :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple matter of binding the click handler of the button to check the value of your input box and checking for a pattern match. Your JavaScript would look something like this:

```
$('#submit_btn').bind('click',function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var patternCheck = [111,222,333].indexOf( parseInt($('#input_field').val()) )
    if( patternCheck !== -1) {
        alert("Found at index "+ patternCheck);
    } else {
        alert("Not found");
    }
});
```

In this case the button has an ID of `submit_btn` and we are raising an `alert` whenever we find a match in an array of values to the value of the input field with an ID of `input_field`.

You may want to store the array of values somewhere else but for illustrating this solution it's easy to just house them within the click handler function. Using `if...elseif` would also work but if you're just looking for exact matches there's no need to iterate/loop through an entire array. This is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object that encapsulates your number and the function?

so:

```
    var groupA = [{
        number: 5,
        action: function() {
            alert('awesome action');
        }
    }];
```

then you could loop over the objects and look for the number,

```
    for(i=0; i<groupA.length; i++) {
        if(groupA[i].number == $("#userInput").val())
            groupA[i].action(); // call the funciton
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch statement to test for a match:

switch($('#input').val()){
       case 'text_to_match_1':
           myfunc1();
           break;
      case 'text_to_match_2':
           myfunc2();
           break;
       case 'text_to_match_3':
           myfunct3();
           break; }

Comment: FYI: this appeared in the low quality posts review queue. Probably because it is code only.